# Better to proxy port 80 or redirect to server:port

Tags: http, nginx

Context is I have a webapp running on port 9001, but want to have `app.company.com` point to my application. I'm not sure if this matters, but I have 2 approaches I can take here.

1. Create a virtual host to proxy HTTP traffic to port 9001.
2. Create a redirect on the domain layer to `server.company.com:9001`

Which would be the better route, and why does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little bit broad, but in general, if you are using a nginx, and it is likely that you application will have some static contents such as css, js, fonts, etc. and you would like the nginx to serve those static content, and only have your app(i.e. the one running at port 9001) to handle the dynamic content, with that in mind, what you could do is for nginx to listen at port 80, and pass the dynamic content to port 9001.

Example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name example.com;

    location /static {
      alias /var/www/html/static;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
      proxy_pass http://server.company.com:9001;
      # other configuration settings here
    }

    # other location configuration here
}
```

Comment: Right so I know I CAN do this, I'm more looking for fundamental pros and cons between the 2. One you've addressed here is serving of static content, but something like Gunicorn could do the same with virtually no performance difference (visibly) so my question is aimed at "Which is better in the most common cases" and "Is it solely preference or are there security/performance" concerns too.

Comment: Personally I prefer to let nginx to handle it before it is reaching to Gunicorn for scalability reason, nginx is designed to handle large traffic and lightweight, so it will better for long run. If you want Gunicorn to handle everything, there is no point to have a nginx in front.

Comment: Right that's a good point. I should have also mentioned being in a corporate environment that's already using nginx, but its a very lightweight tool that Gunicorn handles fine. I think I'll do it right & go the Nginx route.

Comment: One more reason, if your backend is located on the same machine with nginx, in fact you don't even need port 9001, you could setup a Unix socket which is safer and faster, one less port to open is always better for security consideration.

Comment: @hceung another good point, but this server is only accessible on the intranet. Would you still recommend sockets?

Comment: It very easy to use socket setup with Gunicorn with `gunicorn --bind=unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock` versus `gunicorn -- bind=http:0.0.0.0:9001`, this will running in the ram (/tmp) instead of hard disk. Another reason on my suggest approach is that nginx can serve multiple backend web apps in future by just adding new location directive.